# JOOQ BatchDelete records for a list of IDs

Tags: java, sql, database, jooq

I have a list of Objects.

```
List <ObjList> objList;
```

Each object in the list has an ID.
I want to delete all records from the table MyTable which matches the ID from each object in the list.
My list is just a POJO and not an Updatable record. So is there any way I can use the batchDelete method to achieve this?

[From the JavaDocs](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchDelete%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
batchDelete(UpdatableRecord...)  
batchDelete(Collection<? extends UpdatableRecord<?>>)
```

Also, I want to fetch multiple records or columns from MyTable by passing a list of IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your deletion, you may want to think about preferring batch deletion (very large sets of IDs) or bulk deletion (small to medium sized sets of IDs), or a combination of both. With very large sets of IDs, committing from time to time is a good idea, too.

#### Batch deletion:

```
// Assuming this static import:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

using(configuration)
    .batch(
        deleteFrom(MY_TABLE).where(MY_TABLE.ID.eq((Integer) null)))
    .bind(objList
        .stream()
        .map(o -> new Object[] { o.getId() })
        .toArray())
    .execute();
```

#### Bulk deletion:

```
using(configuration)
    .deleteFrom(MY_TABLE).where(MY_TABLE.ID.in(objList
        .stream()
        .map(MyObject::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())))
    .execute();
```